# Backbone client router: how to optimize

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I have the following route configuration:

```
routes: {
    '': 'landing_page', 
    ':show_page': 'show_page', 
    '*actions': 'defaultAction' 
    },
```

"Show page" contains a function that goes somewhat like this:

```
show_page: function(page_name){
        $.get('php/User/check_session.php', _.bind(function(status) {
            if(status == "yes"){
                switch(page_name){

                    case "home": 
                        var home_View = new Home_View(); 
                        app.views.resultView.showView(home_View); 
                        break; 

                    case "parents": 
                        var parent_View = new Parent_View(); 
                        app.views.resultView.showView(parent_View); 
                        break; 

                    case "insurers": 
                        var insurer_View = new Insurer_View(); 
                        app.views.resultView.showView(insurer_View); 
                        break; 

                    case "new_role": 
                        var new_roles_View = new New_roles_View(); 
                        app.views.resultView.showView(new_roles_View); 
                        break; 

                    case "roles_permissions": 
                        var roles_permissions_View = new Roles_permissions_View(); 
                        app.views.resultView.showView(roles_permissions_View); 
                        break; 

                    case "user_roles": 
                        var user_roles_View = new User_roles_View(); 
                        app.views.resultView.showView(user_roles_View); 
                        break; 

                    case "new_accounting": 
                        var input_accounting_View = new Input_accounting_View(); 
                        app.views.resultView.showView(input_accounting_View); 
                        break; 

                    default:
                        var home_View = new Home_View(); 
                        app.views.resultView.showView(home_View); 
                        this.navigate("/home", {trigger:true}); 
                        break; 
                };
etc...
```

Now the problem is that I want to get the route of something like:

```
':show_page/:second_parameter': 'show_page_with_parameter'
```

The thing is that I could manage everything with conditions (switch, or if...then):
Eg. If parent page, then parameter is parent_id. But if new_role page, then parameter is role_id. 
But I already feel as if I am cluttering the router js file.

Is this the right way of doing things, or would you advise me to handle this differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd get rid of the switch statement and have all of your routes explicitly defined in your routes object -- it's easier to understand and see all routes at a glance.

```
routes: {
  '': 'landingPage', 
  'home': 'home', 
  'parents': 'viewParents',
  'parents/:id': 'getParents',
  ...
  '*actions': 'defaultAction' 
},
```

In addition to that, your handlers are very simple right now, but can change in the future. Most could just use:

```
function setView (view, options) {
    app.views.resultView.showView(new view(options));
}
```

With some sort of logged-in validation:

```
function isLoggedIn() {
  return $.get('php/User/check_session.php').then(function (status) {
    if (status !== 'yes')
      throw new Error('Not logged in');
  });
}
```

Or add the log in verification with view setter:

```
function setAuthenticatedView (View, options) {
  return function () {
    isLoggedIn().then(function () {
      setView(View, options);
    });
  }
}
```

And all together:

```
permissionsView: setAuthenticatedView(Permissions_view, {}),
parentsView: setAuthenticatedView(Parents_view, {}),
```

This way you have the ability to extend a route with extra functionality without having a giant switch statement, and for simple routes, you can easily read the source and see that, well, these are authenticated views, and they just set a simple backbone view.

Comment: Thanks for the useful advice, it makes sense to me to rebuild my architecture in the fashion that you propose. I wasn't sure to choose whether to set the paths explicitly or not, but it seems indeed logical that it will be clearer to work out the further routing per menu item. Thank you!